# How to add reply to youtube's video comment using API with PHP

Tags: php, youtube-api

How to add reply to youtube's video comment using API with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library seems to make it pretty easy to add a reply comment: https://github.com/jimdoescode/Zendless-PHP-YouTube-API

```
/**
 * Add a comment to a video or a reply to another comment.
 * To reply to a comment you must specify the commentId
 * otherwise it is just a regular comment.
 *
 * @param string $videoId the video the comment goes with.
 * @param string $comment the comment
 * @param string (optional) $commentId the id of the comment to reply to.
 * @return mixed false if not authenticated otherwise the http response is returned.
 **/

 public function addComment($videoId, $comment, $commentId = false)
```

Answer (score 1):

By searching for a minute I've found this:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments#Adding_a_comment

Looks like the one you need. Of course you need to authenticate the user who wants to post a comment.

To learn how to make a `POST` request in PHP see this article: http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2010/three-ways-to-make-a-post-request-from-php

Comment: Thanks, I saw https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments#Adding_a_comment for replying to video comment on Youtube with PHP but my question here is that in this link post code is given which isn't use any curl.How do i post comment to Youtube using code given in the link? Also, which api should i use for youtube with php.does anyone has source code of it?