# How to insert Youtube comment using Google's API for PHP?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-api-php-client, youtube-data-api

I installed the latest version of the Google API for PHP. Using the example listed [here](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/comment_threads.php), I tried to insert a comment for a video. However, it fails with:

```
Warning: require_once(/var/www/html/youtube/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/YouTube.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/youtube/vendor/google/apiclient/examples/comment_threads.php on line 15

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/youtube/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/YouTube.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/youtube/vendor/google/apiclient/examples/comment_threads.php on line 15
```

Which makes sense, since there is no file 'Youtube.php' in the Service folder of given location. The code is suggesting that there should be, so I'm afraid that the examples are outdated. I'm using version 2.0.0@RC of the Google API PHP (which seems to be te latest). So, my question is: are the examples outdated (if so, how should I insert a Youtube comment?), or are the examples just fine and am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/insert#request) on how to add comments in YouTube API.

The following [code sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/insert#examples) demonstrates how to use the following API methods to create and manage comments:

- It calls the `commentThreads.list` method with the `videoId` parameter set to retrieve comments for a video.
- It calls the `comments.insert` method with the `parentId` parameter set to reply to an existing comment.
- It calls the `comments.list` method with the `parentId` parameter to retrieve the comments in the thread.
- It calls the `comments.update` method with comment in the request body to update a comment.
- It calls the `comments.setModerationStatus` method to set the moderation status of the comment, the `comments.markAsSpam` method to mark the comment as spam, and the `comments.delete` method to delete the comment, using the id parameter to identify the comment.

Also check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915108/how-to-add-reply-to-youtubes-video-comment-using-api-with-php) for more information.